# RSS feed widget for specific categories with latest posts?

Tags: rss, feed

Is there an alternative for default RSS widget? There is one detail that is not working properly.

For example if you have more categories you can add default RSS widgets for each categories. They are displayed like this on the sidebar:

(RSSIMAGE) (CATEGORY TITLE)
(LATEST POSTS)

The problem is that CATEGORY TITLE is hyperlinked - but not to the category page but to the HOME page. Any alternative solution to fix this? I tried with the "SPECIFIC CATEGORY RSS WIDGET" plugin but it can't show latest posts like with DEFAULT RSS widget.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to show posts from a category on the same site you don't need to use RSS widgets. They are used most of the time for showing content from other sites.

Recent posts from your own categories can be shown in widgets with a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-posts/ or the much more powerful Query Posts plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-posts/.

Good luck.